# Mappings, matrices and kernels - two proofs I'm unsure about

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

While scouring through books I use to learn Linear Algebra, I've come across this problem - and it gives me headaches, not least because it does not have solutions. (For anyone wondering: I am self-studying this, which is why I'm still somewhat insecure when it comes to proof writing.) It is the following:

"Let $F:\mathbb{R^n\to R^k}$ and $G:\mathbb{R^n\to R^m}$ be linear mappings with the associated matrices A and B. The matrix C may be given through putting A and B next to each other, yielding
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & ... & a_{1n} \\
... & ... & ... \\
a_{k1} & ... & a_{kn} \\
b_{11} & ... & b_{1n} \\
... & ... & ... \\
b_{m1} & ... & b_{mn} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The mapping belonging to C is $F:\mathbb{R^n\to R^{k+m}}$" So far, so good. I am now to prove:
$\forall x \in \mathbb{R^n}$ it is true that: $H(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
F(x)\\
G(x)\\
\end{pmatrix}$
as well as:
It is true that $kerH = kerF\cap kerG$

At first I had the suspicion that for the first proof I would have to consider both mappings as set and then show, that H is essentially the union of both, represented by the matrix in question. After which, the intersection of the kernels would be rather easy to show, too. But, quite frankly, my attempts led me nowhere, not least because I slowly and plagued by uncertainty realized that I seem to tackle this in a far too computational and set theoretic manner. Now, I am lost and in need of some advice. Thus, any help would be welcome.

Thanks in advance everybody!

Comment: Which book is this problem from?

Comment: I believe you mean "The mapping belonging to C is $H:\mathbb{R^n\to R^{k+m}}$"

Comment: **HINT**: $(F(x),G(x)) = (0,0)$ if and only if $F(x)=0=G(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\ker(H)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|H(x)=0_{k+m,1}\}$$ and $$\ker(F)\cap\ker(G)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|F(x)=0_{k,1} \ \ \text{and} \ \ G(x)=0_{m,1}\}.$$Now, use the hint given by Ted Shifrin to prove that $$\ker(H)=\ker(F)\cap\ker(G).$$